# SQL Report Server Data Source

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rdlc, sqlreportingservice

we currently have an asp mvc site that's serving rdlc files without sql report server. That data is modeled in the code and then passed to the rdlc file which generates the report.

```
reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("dataset", contactListsDataSet);
LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
```

Something like the above. It all works great however what I'd like to allow is for the end user to be able to modify the look and feel of the report.

Currently the only way I can think of doing it is getting them to download SQL Server Report Builder and then download the rdlc template modify it and re upload the template. This just feels a bit clunky and if you click run in Report Builder is fails because there is no data source.

So my second thought was to setup SQL Report Server and from what I understand this facilitates the downloading and uploading of rdlc files once you've connected to the server. My problems with this and what my actual question.

Can SQL Report Server use a api/code end point and not directly access the database for the data? We do some calculations and structuring of the data and our reports are based on that and not the raw sql results?

We have multiple clients on one database and their data has a client_id on it where necessary so they only see there own data. For reports we'd only want a client to see their own modified reports. Can SQL Report Server handle multi tenancy?

Thanks

Comment: If what you are asking is for a layer of abstraction between the report and the DB schema, then you could point the reports Dataset to a stored procedure on the schema that accepts parameters that will allow you to control the data retrieved.

Comment: @DaniDev wanted to avoid a stored procedure but thanks

Comment: Just Out of curiosity, what is the reason that you wanted to avoid Stored Procedure(s)? (Doesn't sound like it's a access/permissions issue)

Comment: @DaniDev the data is already being fetched and calculations are already made in the code so to move that all to stored procedures would be more work than its worth to achieve custom forms layouts per client. I can allow users to upload rdlc files and manage it all myself just thought report server might be cleaner

Comment: I guess I misunderstood: "Can SQL Report Server use a api/code end point ?"  I thought you were asking for some layer where you could implement some "filtering" based on who the end user (client) is?

Comment: @DaniDev that's part of it and if it was just that then stored procedures would work however we also calculate final marks based on assessment marks which is done in the code because the calculation is configurable. Don't wanna have to move that to stored procedures

Comment: As I understand the architecture from your description, I don't think you would have to as the calculations take place post data retrieval, No?